# Validacion de campos de formulario

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Quiero validar todos los campos del formulario; `nombre`, `edad`, `lista` (select), `terms` (checkbox).

De tal forma que salte un alert y el formulario no se envie cuando el campo `nombre` este vacio, no se haya escogido ningun option de la lista `lista`, y cuando no esté marcado el checkbox `terms`

Con la edad lo he conseguido de tal forma que solo deja introducir edades entre 18 y 65 pero no salta error cuando el campo está vacio.

Lo necesito en Javascript puro.

```js
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="libreria.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  
  function validate(){
  
   var edad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
   var name = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
   var lista = document.getElementById('lista').value;
   
   if(name.length == 0){
     alert('Introduce un nombre');
     return false;
   }

   if(edad<18 || edad>65 || (edad="")){
     alert('Acceso restringido a edades no comprendidas entre 18 y 65 años');
     return false; 
    }

   if(lista == ""){
     alert('Debe Elegir una opcion en la lista');
     return false;
   }
     
   if(!document.getElementById('terms').checked){
     alert('Necesario aceptar los Términos y condiciones');
     return false;
    }
   return true;
  }
  
  </script>
 </head>
```

```html
<body>
  
 <form onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="procesa.php">
 <fieldset>
  
  <table class="" >
   <tr>
    <td>
     Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre"class="inputs" style="width: 130px" required><br><br>&nbsp;
    </td>

    <td>
     Edad: <input type="number" id="edad" class="inputs" style="width: 80px"><br><br>&nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
     Sexo: <input type="radio" id="r1" class="inputs" name="genero"><label for="r1">Masculino</label>
     <input type="radio"  id="r2" class="inputs" name="genero"><label for="r2">Femenino</label><br>&nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>
     Aceptar términos y condiciones: <input type="checkbox" id="terms" class="" name="terms" required><br>&nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td>
      Ciudad<select id="lista">
          <option value="1" disabled selected value>Elige una opcion</option>
          <option value="Sevilla">Sevilla</option>
          <option value="Cordoba">Cordoba</option>
          <option value="Granada">Granada</option>
          <option value="Cádiz">Cádiz</option>
         </select><br>&nbsp;
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="submit" onClick="">
     </td>
   </tr>

  </table>

 </fieldset>
 
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el if del campo "nombre" intenta reemplazando la variable `name.length == 0;` por la variable `name == "";`

El if que tienes con el campo "edad" déjalo de la siguiente forma:

```
if(edad<18 || edad>65){
    alert('Acceso restringido a edades no comprendidas entre 18 y 65 años');
    return false;   
}
```

Luego crea otro if seguido de ese para verificar que el campo no este vacío:

```
if(edad==""){
    alert('El campo edad no puede estar vacío');
}
```

En el la lista, la primera opción que tienes pon `value=""` indicando de esta forma que el primer campo no tiene valor alguno.
Luego dentro de tu función `validate()` pon lo siguiente:

```
ciudad = document.getElementById("lista").selectedIndex;
if( ciudad == null || ciudad == 0 ) {
    alert('Debes seleccionar una ciudad');
    return false;
}
```

Para el checkbox, debes poner lo siguiente:

```
casilla = document.getElementById("terms");
if( !casilla.checked ) {
    alert('Debe aceptar los terminos y condiciones');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he conseguido resolver la edad, pero los demás campos no se me validan y por lo tanto se envia el formulario.

Comment: @AlejandroCastroEcija he actualizado la respuesta, espero haber resuelto tus dudas, saludos.

Comment: NO puse nada, muchas gracias @Diego Mansilla por tu ayuda y aportación, conseguí resolver el código!!

Comment: @AlejandroCastroEcija seria genial que lo marcaras como respuesta para ayudar a los demas que tengan las mismas dudas que tu, saludos!!

Comment: @AlejandroCastroEcija Podrias marcar como respuesta por favor, ya que me han bloqueado la cuenta por no tener puntuacion en mis respuestas, gracias.